# Why won't my bots send its embedded message but will send everything else fine?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Below code won't send the embedded message in my server when I use the dailygacha command. However every other command works fine. Any links to documentation I can read up on would also be greatly appreciated so I can further understand how any of your solutions work. Thank you in advance.

```
α = 75,67,70
β = 90,95,78
γ = 86,18,10
δ = 9,56,93
ε = 117, 85, 138
ζ = 232, 99, 202
rarity = random.choices("αβγδεζ", weights=[60, 40, 20, 15, 5, 3])

strength = random.randint(0, 100)
agility = random.randint(0, 100)
defense = random.randint(0, 100)
endurance = random.randint(0, 100)
csi = ((strength + agility + defense + endurance) / 4)


@bot.command()
@commands.cooldown(1, 60*60*24, commands.BucketType.user)
async def dailygacha(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(
    colour = discord.Colour.to_rgb(rarity),
    title = "Waifu Gacha",
    description = f"Roll Result: Lelouch Lamperouge [{rarity}]",
    )
    embed.set_image(url="https://cdn.myanimelist.net/images/characters/5/274017.jpg")
    embed.add_field(name="Character Stats:", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name=f"Strength: {strength}", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name=f"Agility: {agility}", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name=f"Defense: {defense}", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name=f"Endurance: {endurance}", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name=f"Total CSI: {csi}", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="Roll Type:", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="Daily", inline=False)

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide a traceback, so please try to do so in future if possible.

The reason this is happening is because `add_field()` *requires* both the `name` and `value` keyword arguments. I'd suggest either moving each of the variables (`strength`, `agility` etc.) into the `value`, or you can have a blank `value` field by using the `u200b` character.

Here are both methods:

```py
embed.add_field(name=f"Strength: {strength}", value="\u200b")
# OR
embed.add_field(name="Strength:", value=f"{strength}")
```

`\u200b` is a [zero-width space](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm) and will still count as a string with a character in it, but won't nag you for being empty.

---

**Edit:**

It seems another issue is your `rarity`.
First of all, I wouldn't recommend using non-ascii characters.
Second of all, your `rarity` isn't actually returning what you think it is.

It's returning a list with a random character as the only element.
To fix it, you can do one of the following:

```py
r, g, b = locals()[rarity[0]]
discord.Colour.from_rgb(r, g, b)
# OR
rarity = random.choices([α, β, γ, δ, ε, ζ], weights=[60, 40, 20, 15, 5, 3])
r, g, b = rarity[0]
discord.Colour.from_rgb(r, g, b)
```

---

**Another edit:**

```py
letter = rarity[0] # Gets the letter you assigned to each tuple
r, g, b = locals()[rarity[0]] # Gets the tuple of rgb values

# Add multiple new lines to a field
embed.add_field(name="Character stats:", value=f"Strength: {strength}\nAgility: {agility} ...")
```

---

**References:**

- [Zero-width space](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm)
- [`Embed.add_field()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Embed.add_field)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216184/discussion-on-answer-by-diggy-why-wont-my-bots-send-its-embedded-message-but-w).